# How can I create new project in Trac?

Tags: windows, trac

I have installed Bitnami Trac for windows. (bitnami-trac-0.12.2-5-windows-installer) 
During installation, it asked me for creating project and username and password.
I successfully created project and set up a user for me(admin).
At the moment, there is written only one available project that I created during installation. 
I am new to it, that is why I am asking it from you,

1. Please help me how can I create new project?
2. Also, how can I create other users?

Comment: Please edit your question to not ask questions twice here at SO. Your first one here looks not very different to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002427/trac-admin-path-to-myproject-initenv - in fact even less detailed. And as bta's answer is pointing out, you should really look at standard places for available documentation (most authoritative is Trac wiki at trac.edgewall.org) before asking for more here.

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami installer asks for creating a project because it means to create a new Trac instance with its database (.db file). The terms are a bit misleading here.

The question is, if you want to create another separate Trac database, it's own Trac world of itself so to speak. In that case you must use the approach of Phil's answer and use `trac-admin.exe initenv` on command-line. The new Trac instance must be added as new `<Location>` in Apache's `httpd.conf` then.

If you just want to have a second user-project in your Trac instance, you should solve it on the level of Trac plugins, and install for instance `SimpleMultiProjectPlugin` where you can create multiple user-projects for your single Trac site.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new project "environment" with the following command:

$ trac-admin /path/to/myproject initenv

(Needless to say, you'll need admin rights and open a terminal window on your Trac server to do this.) It's described at http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall#CreatingaProjectEnvironment.

Managing users is described here, https://superuser.com/questions/266309/managing-trac-users.