# trac-admin /path/to/myproject initenv

Tags: trac

I have a problem with Trac.

I cant create a new project.

Here, in the /path/to/myproject - what should I write instead of it?

In fact, my project path is: C:\Users\Programmer\BitNami Trac Stack projects

Everytime it outputs error in BitNami Trac Stack command line.

Why cant I create a new project?

It is writing: The system cannot find the path specified

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried trac-admin c:/Users/Programmer/BitNami initenv ?

Comment: What is the exact command you are trying? I suspect you are missing quotes around the path, which is necessary when it contains spaces.

Comment: @user859955, I tried it, and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: ok - great. I will convert my comment into an answer then

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`cd C:\Users\Programmer\BitNami`

`trac-admin . initenv`

Answer (score 0):

You could save yourself a lot of hassle by avoiding blanks/spaces (and non-ASCII characters) in paths, at least if you expect to go to the command line. This always tends to become a pain.

Therefore reinstalling is a real option, because I know you can change path defaults to saner values without blanks/spaces. I did this before, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your case to create a new project, use:

```
trac-admin c:/Users/Programmer/BitNami initenv
```